# Как работает Babel CDN с кодом

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, babel

Здравствуйе, недавно начал знакомство с babel, но возник вопрос, не могу понять, как рабоатет babel который мы подключаем через CDN к станице, как он берет код, которорый находиться в script на странице и делает свои манипуляции, веди CDN бабеля это просто статический файл с набором функций.

*Кто знает как это работает, пожалуйста отпишитесь, буду очень благодарен!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При загрузке в браузере babel(@babel/standalone) автоматически скомпилирует и выполнит все теги скрипта с типом *text/babel* или *text/jsx*

[Взято отсюда](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#usage)

После загрузки из CDN, Babel запускается через *IIFE* и транспилирует код кладя его в `<head>`

Пример где `<style>` в `<head>` появился только после загрузки Babel:

[image: Работа babel]